# Use of scanner.hasNext()

Tags: java, function, loops

i have tried a lot of websites and none of em give me the proper use of **hasNext() function in JAVA** . I learnt that it scans untill there are no more inputs? What does it mean by no more inputs? The user will already know how many inputs it will provide. And when does the function stop? Please help me understand this function. Thanks.

Comment: It, err, tells you whether the input contains another token. If it doesn't, you are at end of stream. 'The user will already know how many inputs it will provide' is false in the general case.

Comment: `Scanner` isn't only used for cases where user input is required. You can use `System.in` to scan data entered into the console (by a user), or you could use a `FileInputStream` to scan the contents of a file. There are other uses aswell, such as scanning over a `String`.

Comment: NB Don't 'try a lot of websites'. 99% of them are rubbish. Use the offical documentation and tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

if you see below code from Scanner.class , you will get to know your answer.

```
/**
 * Returns true if this scanner has another token in its input.
 * This method may block while waiting for input to scan.
 * The scanner does not advance past any input.
 *
 * @return true if and only if this scanner has another token
 * @throws IllegalStateException if this scanner is closed
 * @see java.util.Iterator
 */
public boolean hasNext() {
    ensureOpen();
    saveState();
    while (!sourceClosed) {
        if (hasTokenInBuffer())
            return revertState(true);
        readInput();
    }
    boolean result = hasTokenInBuffer();
    return revertState(result);
}
```

If you see the above code ensureOpen() Method make sure that Scanner is open or closed, post the state is validated, which means that till your cursor is taking input , it will validate the info form Scanner Constructor with parameter.

Here When you define, the below code.

```
Scanner out = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Here, Creating new Scanner resource takes System Input as a stream. Below Constructor with parameter do the task.

```
 /**
 * Constructs a new <code>Scanner</code> that produces values scanned
 * from the specified input stream. Bytes from the stream are converted
 * into characters using the underlying platform's
 * {@linkplain java.nio.charset.Charset#defaultCharset() default charset}.
 *
 * @param  source An input stream to be scanned
 */
public Scanner(InputStream source) {
    this(new InputStreamReader(source), WHITESPACE_PATTERN); // Below is the description
}
```

Here in the above Comment Marked  code , the call goes to the java.io.InputStream class, which make sure that reading is taken from console till the user is providing the input.

Hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

So here's the scoop: hasNext() does scan until there are no more user inputs. It just means that the program keeps going if there are still remaining inputs to scan. It stops scanning when all of the user inputs has been scanned. The function stops when the input block is empty. For example, say you put in 5 inputs. The system keeps running until all 5 inputs have been scanned.